# /var/log/syslog constantly logging errors, growing at 1 MB/s

Tags: uefi, cinnamon, mint, syslog

It seems to be the same three errors repeated:

```
$ tail -n15 /var/log/syslog
Apr  5 23:32:01 detoo kernel: [ 6042.078785] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150619/psargs-359)
Apr  5 23:32:01 detoo kernel: [ 6042.078787] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808554d42d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150619/psparse-536)
Apr  5 23:32:01 detoo kernel: [ 6042.078788] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150619/evgpe-592)
```

I noticed something was wrong when I was getting low disk space warnings. I've flashed to the latest UEFI available, I've tried enabling/disabling the C states in my UEFI.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit with kernel 4.2.0-34-generic. I have a skylake processor and z170 motherboard.

I'm quite new to linux and am at a lost as what I should do next.

EDIT: I have the same problem when booting from a USB with Ubuntu 16.04, and nearly identical error logs being constantly spammed:

```
Apr  6 01:01:48 ubuntu kernel: [  152.594053] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
Apr  6 01:01:48 ubuntu kernel: [  152.594994] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)
Apr  6 01:01:48 ubuntu kernel: [  152.594996] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808554e02d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the latest hardware - Skylake came out Q3-2015, Z170 board as well. The 4.2.0 kernel came out at the same time, so development for it was *before* board and CPU were widely available. Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu Trusty, which is even older.

Try with a Live CD of Ubuntu Xenial to see if your hardware is better supported by kernel 4.4.0. If you want to have the latest hardware, you better run the latest Linux on it for best support.

Even the current beta of 16.04 probably is a better fit for your system, with less issues.

EDIT: To have a quick fix for the issue at hand, do `sudo echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F`. This should temporarily disable the GPE and get rid of the messages. You probably need a BIOS update to fix the issue.

Comment: I've booted ubuntu 16.04 from a USB with the same problem.

Comment: @roro: I updated my answer with specific information. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242013/disable-gpe-acpi-interrupts-on-boot has more details.

Comment: I'm getting permission denied, even with sudo. 

... ... ...

Opening it as sudo vim gives the error: "/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F" E667: Fsync failed
WARNING: Original file may be lost or damaged
don't quit the editor until the file is successfully written!

... ... ....

Opening it as sudo nano gives the error:  Error writing /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F: Invalid argument

Comment: got it to work by sudo -s

Comment: `sudo echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F` cannot work, because the `sudo` works only for the `echo` command, but not for the `>` redirection (which is done by the shell). You can use `echo "disable" | sudo tee /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F` or `echo "disable" | sudo dd of=/sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F`.

Comment: Since Linux 4.10, you need to use the keyword "mask" instead of "disable":
`echo "mask" | sudo tee /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F`